# When I run my pygame script I see a blank screen with some glitch on the screen

Tags: python, pygame

I can't seem to see my images, even though I put the image in the same project
when I run it I see a blank screen with some glitch and I don't see
what I am trying to do

See the code:

```
    import pygame
    pygame.init()
    from tkinter import *

    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1024, 1024))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Punch King")
    walkRight = [pygame.image.load("Taunt chefff.png")]
    walkLeft = [pygame.image.load("spr_swi_blockhigh_strip3.png")]
    standing = [pygame.image.load("spr_swi_p_strip2.png")]
    link = "https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=Kiddacoder"

     x = 40
     y = 550
     width = 60
     height = 80    
     vel = 10
     isJump = False
     left = False
     right = False 
     jumpCount = 10
     walkCount = 0
     run = True
     while run:
         pygame.time.delay(100)

         for event in pygame.event.get():
              if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                   run = False
                   pygame.quit()`
```

This is just a piece of the code. Please I need help.

Comment: Please do fix the indentation of the code.

Comment: What is the goal of your script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fist,
you're not actually drawing anything to the screen. for that you need to write
screen.blit(,(x,y))

second,
you're not updating (refreshing) the screen. Use the
pygame.display.update()
or pygame.display.flip() function after you've blited everything to the screen

it's not clear what you are trying to do.. but it seems like you're trying to draw image of a character and change it (left or right) depending on the inputs,if that is so, or if yoy wanna move anything,
you will have to draw everything inside the while loop

here's the code

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1024, 1024))
pygame.display.set_caption("Punch King")

images = [pygame.image.load('spr_swi_p_strip2.png'),
      pygame.image.load('spr_swi_blockhigh_strip3.png'),
      pygame.image.load('Taunt chefff.png')]

mode = 'stand'
run = True
while run:

for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            mode = "left"
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            mode = "right"
        if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
            mode = "stand"
    if mode == 'stand':
        screen.blit(images[0],(<your x coordinate>,<your y coordinate>))
    if mode == 'left':
        screen.blit(images[1],(<x>,<y>))
    if mode == 'right':
        screen.blit(images[2],(<x>,<y>))

    pygame.display.flip()
```

make the necessary changes according to yoy're program :)